# Which Exception Do I Throw in This Case?

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception

I'm having a problem with this block of code here. I want to be able to display the output of a file that only contains the words "LANTALK". My catch doesn't seem to be right though. Do you know which exception I should throw in this case?

```
try {
    sc = new Scanner(filename);

    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String line=sc.nextLine();

        if(line.contains("LANTALK"))
            System.out.println(line);
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("The file \""+log+"\" was not found"); 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not right"? FYI `IOException` is the parent of `FileNotFoundException`, in case you have I/O issues other than the file not being found.

Comment: just e.printStacktrace()

Comment: Meaning it won't compile, sorry. The IOException will not let it compile either.

Comment: You can create your own exception, just create a class and extend Exception

Comment: I've got it working now with the e.printStackTrace(). Thanks guys!

Comment: ill add that as an answer then if it worked!:)

Answer (score 0):

just use e.printStackTrace()

```
try
  {
    sc = new Scanner(filename);
        while(sc.hasNext())

          {
            String line=sc.nextLine();
            if(line.contains("LANTALK"))
            System.out.println(line);
          }

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
          {
              e.printStackTrace(); 
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all depends on how this method and possible exceptions would be processed.
Probably you should not throw an exception but return boolean that represents if the file contains that keyword. For example:

```
private boolean isValidFile(final String filename) throws IOException
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.contains("LANTALK"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```